# LaunchScreen.storyboard bug in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I was using LaunchScreen.storyboard without problems.
but I changed LaunchScreen.storyboard file name to LaunchScreen2.storyboard since I hoped not to use the splash image.
(I thought it could decrease loading time)
However, I couldn't see the loading time differences.

So I renamed the file to LaunchScreen.storyboard to use splash image again.
But the problem began from here.

Even though I change images in LaunchScreen.Storyboard:-

1. Only black screen is shown shortly when I run my app on simulators.
2. Old LaunscScreen.storyboard is shown when I run the app on my iPad.

I took some.. actions but it didn't work.
(use image in Assets.cassettes, make sure Launch Screen File name in project option)

Is there anyone who can help me?

*I attached screenshots
[image: my project setting]

[image: LaunchScreen.storyboard detail]

(I'm using the latest Xcode, Version 9.1 (9B55))

Comment: 1) Delete the app. 2) Clean your project. 3) General --> App Icon and Launch Images --> Launch Screen file --> Make sure name is correct here of your  LaunchScreen.storyboard 4) Run you app in device

Comment: Hi ChanWarde, I followed your guide but now the device also shows short black screen like in simulators.. and I linked my screenshots.

Comment: Share a screenshot of your launch screen which you are expecting to show on start.

Comment: I've just shared the link.(I can't attach images because of my low reputations).

Comment: I've just attached the images. Thank you.

Comment: It looks like you did everything correctly. Try to clear out you derived data.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to clear derived data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found out the root cause of the issue that lasted for more than a month.

At least in my case, the issue was occurred because there was no entry point in the LaunchScreen file.
After entry point was set I could see the LaunchScreen.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is iOS issue(OS Level) iOS caching LaunchScreen.storyboard image resource and reuse it

why your action did't work because

1. app on simulators have not cached LaunchScreen so show black screen(LaunchScreen.storyboard not found)
2. iPad has cached and used LaunchScreen Resource(LaunchScreen.storyboard) so old Resource shown

Common solution is delete app or shut down and on iPhone or iPad for removing cashed resource. iOS mananing this resource in Srpingboard(OS Level) so It is not a complete solution but promotes the cache to be quickly erased from OS. just waiting.. until iOS erase it

Comment: Hi Cruz. Now the problem is that the iPad also shows black screen shortly after I deleted the app and re-installed the app. Have you ever seen this issue?..

Comment: @mazend yes have ever seen this issue it is possible show after delete and reinstall app because resource exist in Springboard also reinstall new version from appstore. Resources have a very strong dependency on OS

Comment: How long do I have to wait to resolve this issue on the average? I rebooted my iPad but the issue is not resolved. In addition I have been seeing this issue on simulators for about 2 weeks.